# How can I access the globalPropeties from another component in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

From the main of the application I created a global propertie called $configuration and it is found in app, but I don't know how I have to access it from some other component of the application.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import router from '@/infrastructure/router'
import vuetify from '@plugins/vuetify'
import configurator from '@plugins/configurator'

const app = createApp(App)

await configurator
    .getConfig()
    .then((response: any) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$configuration = response
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(vuetify)
app.mount('#app')
```

I tried to use getCurrentInstance but I have the problem that it doesn't type $configuration. Is there another way to get $configuration without having to use getCurrentIntance ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG3SJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can create a file or do it in each file where you are using your global properties. My way of doing it here is created a useConfiguration.ts file containing:

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

export function useConfiguration(): any | undefined {
  const vm = getCurrentInstance();

  return vm?.appContext.config.globalProperties.$configuration;
}
```

After that if you want to type your global properties you can use this in your main.ts or in a dedicated file :

```
declare module 'vue' {
  export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $configuration: typeof response/yourType;
  }
}
```

Now you can change the return type **any** of your function with the real type and your variable will be typed.

I wouldn't use **proxy** from **getCurrentInstance**, it's more used to get the reactive proxy object of the component. By using this, you can change the reactive data.

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCurrentInstance` method in composition-api.

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

const { proxy } = getCurrentInstance();
```

then:

```js
proxy.$configuration
```